# How to calculate a date difference in calendar months?

Tags: php, datetime, date-math

```
$time_start = mktime(12,0,0,1,1,2011);
$time_end = mktime(12,0,0,7,1,2011);
$format = '%m months';

$start_date = new DateTime(date(DATE_ATOM,$time_start));
$end_date = new DateTime(date(DATE_ATOM,$time_end));
$diff = $start_date->diff($end_date, true);
echo $diff->format($format);
```

Outputs "5 months", I guess because it's off by an hour due to DST. However, I need to calculate the difference in calendar months; is there another class/function that will do this?

---

Added some fixes:

```
if($time_start > $time_end) list($time_start, $time_end) = array($time_end, $time_start);
$time_end += (date('I',$time_end)-date('I',$time_start))*3600; // correct for DST
$start_date = new DateTime(date(DATE_ATOM,$time_start));
$end_date = new DateTime(date(DATE_ATOM,$time_end));
$start_date->modify('12pm'); // ignore time difference
$end_date->modify('12pm');
$diff = $start_date->diff($end_date);
echo $diff->format($format);
```

This seems to give the results I want, but I haven't fully tested it yet.

---

More fixes, based on Herbert's suggestions:

```
if($time_start > $time_end) list($time_start, $time_end) = array($time_end, $time_start);
$start_date = new DateTime();
$end_date = new DateTime();
$start_date->setTimestamp($time_start);
$end_date->setTimestamp($time_end);
$diff = $start_date->diff($end_date);
$hours = $diff->format('%h');
$mins = $diff->format('%i');
$secs = $diff->format('%s');
$start_date->setTime(12,0,0);//ignore time difference for date calculations
$end_date->setTime(12,0,0);
$diff = $start_date->diff($end_date);
$years = $diff->format('%y');
$months = $diff->format('%m');
$weeks = $diff->format('%w');
$days = $diff->format('%d');
```

Note that the `$start_date->modify('12pm')` wasn't actually doing anything at all. Not sure why it didn't error.

Comment: It's probably 5 months 29 days or something - try outputting the full period including days (`%m` gives you only the month *portion* of the full date)

Comment: Come on Mark. With 15k you shouldn't be so quick to throw around the word *bug*. `var_dump($diff);` and see what **Pekka** mentioned.

Comment: Well you're both correct that it says 5 months, 29 days, 23 hours (DST I guess), but that's not really the point. If a human looked at those 2 dates, he would think they are 6 months apart because they differ by 6 calendar months. That's the answer I need.

Comment: Then `DateDiff::format` may not be the right thing for you - maybe you need to check out a "nice dates" library that rounds up periods in a way that makes sense to humans.

Comment: I get 6 months exaclty. Curious.

Comment: @Herbert: Do you observe DST where you live (or where your server is)? Probably different locale settings.

Comment: Yeah, it's currently EDT here and my test server is on my machine. I just copied and pasted your original code (just now noticed the update) and got _exactly_ 6 months. `var_dump` yields `public 'days' => int 6015`

Comment: Hold on. `date_default_timezone_get()` reveals UTC. Maybe that's it?

Comment: @Herbert: Mine appears to be set to `America/Los_Angeles`. Could be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

After messing around with a lot of different ideas it occurred to me that timestamps are in GMT (UTC). `date(DATE_ATOM,$time_start)` is applying the default timezone. However, if you set the timestamp *explicitly*, `DateTime` will assume UTC — thus, no DST problem.

The following code *seems* to work regardless of timezone or DST.

```
<?php

$time_start = mktime(12,0,0,1,1,2011);
$time_end = mktime(12,0,0,7,1,2011)

$start_date = new DateTime();
$end_date = new DateTime();

$start_date->setTimestamp($time_start);
$end_date->setTimestamp($time_end);

$diff = $start_date->diff($end_date);

$format = '%m months';
echo $diff->format($format);

?>
```

I tested *some* edge cases — both date and time, and a variety of timezones — but I haven’t tested *every* possibility so if you come across an issue, I’d be interested in hearing about it.

Comment: I suspect the UTC trick will fail when switching to UTC causes the day to change. It's also possible that my trick could have the same effect if I didn't add/subtract the hour in the right place...

Comment: This is an interesting problem and I fully intend to keep working on it. :-)

Comment: @Mark: I think I found a solution.

Comment: I think you might be right. Unix timestamps are always in GMT, so if we stay consistent with that, I think we should be safe. Thanks for all your help! I'll let you know if I come across any issues with this.

Comment: Dumping `$start_date` after calling `setTimestamp` actually does show my default timezone, not GMT/UTC...but it still seems to work.

Comment: That's odd. Maybe it's a formatting thing. Nevertheless, internally it seems to see it as UTC. Hey, as long as it works... :-)